# Can I run/use 3 feature files with a single step definition file in cucumber Java

Tags: cucumber-jvm

Can I run/use  3 feature files  with a single step definition file in cucumber Java? Does cucumber java supports this?

I have the following feature files:

```
login.feature
registration.feature
search.feature
```

I need to implement only 1 step-definition.java file 
    for the 3  feature files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use as many or as few files as you want to. But I would recommend splitting your step definitions into classes that correspond with the steps. Here are two suggestions as to how you could do it.

```
login.feature
registration.feature
search.feature 

LoginStepDefs.java
RegistrationStepDefs.java
SearchStepDefs.java
```

or per page

```
login.feature
registration.feature
search.feature 

LoginPageStepDefs.java
RegistrationPageStepDefs.java
SearchPageStepDefs.java
SearchResultPageStepDefs.java
```

Whatever you choose, make sure your CucumberRunner is configured to pick up the glue code (step definitions).

Comment: Thanks for the reply David .But will it be possible to do the following ? For all three .feature file only one stepdefinition.java containing step definitions for all three .feature files  . Does cucumber-jvm  support this ?

Comment: Hi @PramodKumar , yes you can. Cucumber-jvm does not care whether you put all your steps in one file.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a step for one feature and if the step makes sense and the logic is the same you can use it on other feature files without creating another step.